# Spring How to create links/scrolling/ next previous page?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Software: Spring MVC, Java, Hibernate, JSTLs

Query: I have (say) 50 unique employee recoerds in database. Only 10 records (say names of employee as href) are displayed on the page. How can I create a link that can (say 1 | 2 | 3 or Next | Previous) in Spring MVC to select next 10 or previous 10?

What I am able to do is to display 10 records on the JSP page. This is done by selecting the first 10 employee from the database and passing that as modelAttribute to JSP page.

Sorry, I don't have any idea how this can be done, either spring provide any annotations or classes. Any so any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `pagination` to your jsp and instead of passing the `10` records from your database , you can select all records and pass it to your jsp .

Check [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) which takes care of displaying paginated records.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just to update you.. your comment has surely gave me a pointer and I am very thankful to you for that...I am still working on observing the pagination concept and searching on google..

Comment: Glad i could help you :) post here if you find any issues in applying pagination